# Scipy: how to obtain bivariate empirical density probability distribution (not by KDE)?

Tags: python

My data are stored discretely, e.g. 1, 2, 3 ....

For 1 dimension, the empirical density probability function would look like a histogram.

[image]

And for 2 dimensions, it will look like a bivairate histogram, and how can I obtain it? (I can obtain one by Kernel Density Estimation, but that result is often smoothed by the gaussian kernel. I want a un-smoothed pdf in this case.)

Comment: Do you want the function or the histogram display itself?

Comment: @BrenBarn function. I can make the histogram by `numpy`. I remember there is a function for that.

Comment: If your data is discrete, you could use something like `value_counts` or `pivot_table` in `pandas` to just get a frequency count of how often each value occurs.